# Parsing txt file using python : List index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, readfile

Hello I have written a python program to parse data specific data from txt file
my code is:

```
f = open('C:/Users/aikaterini/Desktop/Ericsson_PARSER/BSC_alarms_vf_OSS.txt','r')
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb



def firstl():

    with f as lines:
        lines = lines.readlines()
        print len(lines)
        for i,line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith("*** Disconnected from"):
                conline = line.split()
                bsc = conline[-2]
                print "\n"*5
                print bsc
                print "*"*70
                break


        for i,line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith("*** Connected to"):
                conline = line.split()
                bsc = conline[-2]
                print "\n"*5
                print bsc
                print "*"*70

            elif line[:3] == "A1/" or line[:3] == "A2/":

                if  lines[i+1].startswith("RADIO"):
                    fal = line.split()
                    first_alarm_line = [fal[0][:2],fal[-2],fal[-1]]
                    year = first_alarm_line[1][:2]
                    month = first_alarm_line[1][2:4]
                    day = first_alarm_line[1][4:]
                    hours = first_alarm_line[2][:2]
                    minutes = first_alarm_line[2][2:]
                    date = datetime.strptime( day + " " + month + " " + year + " " + \
                                              hours+":"+minutes,"%d %m %y %H:%M")


                    print first_alarm_line
                    print date, "\n"
                    print lines[i+1]
                    print lines[i+4]
                    print lines[i+5]
                    desc_line = lines[i+4]
                    desc_values_line = lines[i+5]
                    desc = desc_line.split(None,2)
                    print desc

                    desc_values = desc_values_line.split(None,2)
                    rsite = ""

                    #for x in desc_values[1]:
                     #   if not (x.isalpha() or x == "0"):
                      #      rsite += x
                    rsite = desc_values[1].lstrip('RBS0')
                    print "\t"*2 + "rsite:" + rsite 

                    if desc[-1] == "ALARM SLOGAN\n":
                        alarm_slogan = desc_values[-1]
                        print alarm_slogan



                    x = i
                    print x # to check the line
                    print len(line) #check length of lines
                    while not lines[x].startswith("EXTERNAL"):
                        x+=1
                    if lines[x].startswith("EXTERNAL"):
                        while not lines[x] == "\n":
                            print lines[x]
                            x+=1


                    print "\n"*5


                elif lines[i+1].startswith("CELL LOGICAL"):
                    fal = line.split()
                    first_alarm_line = [fal[0][:2],fal[-2],fal[-1]]
                    #print i
                    print first_alarm_line

                    type = lines[i+1]
                    print type
                    cell_line = lines[i+3]
                    cell = cell_line.split()[0]
                    print cell
                    print "\n"*5



          ##########Database query###########

            #db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,password,database)





    firstl()
```

when i run the program the results are correct 
but it prints until line 50672 while there are 51027
and i get the last printed result with the following error:

```
['A2', '130919', '0309']
2013-09-19 03:09:00 

RADIO X-CEIVER ADMINISTRATION

MO                                 RSITE           ALARM SLOGAN

RXOCF-18                           RBS03668        OML FAULT

['MO', 'RSITE', 'ALARM SLOGAN\n']
    rsite:3668
OML FAULT

50672
51027

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\parser_v3.py", line 106, in <module>
 firstl()
File "C:\Python27\parser_v3.py", line 72, in firstl
   while not lines[x].startswith("EXTERNAL"):
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

if i comment the while not line i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\parser_v3.py", line 106, in <module>
 firstl()
  File "C:\Python27\parser_v3.py", line 60, in firstl
   rsite = desc_values[1].lstrip('RBS0')
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

The txt content is like :

```
 A1/EXT "FS G11B/25/13/3" 382 150308   1431      
RADIO X-CEIVER ADMINISTRATION
BTS EXTERNAL FAULT

MO                RSITE            CLASS
RXOCF-16          RBS02190         1

EXTERNAL ALARM
ALARM SYSTEM ON/OFF    G2190 DRAMA CNR                        



A1/EXT "FS G11B/25/13/3" 755 150312   1434      
RADIO X-CEIVER ADMINISTRATION
BTS EXTERNAL FAULT

MO                RSITE            CLASS
RXOCF-113         RBS00674         1

EXTERNAL ALARM
IS.BOAR FAIL    G0674 FALAKRO
```

I don't understand since i do  a split with maxnumber 2 and i get 3 elements as u can see and i am picking the 2nd and if i comment that i get another error when i pick an element from a list and the thing is that returning the correct result.Please help me.
Sorry for the long post thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm haven't dug deep into your code, but have you tried validating that `x` does not exceed the number of elements in `lines` before trying to access that index? Also, for readability I'd suggest using `lines[x] !=` rather than `not lines[x] ==`

```
while x < len(lines) and lines[x] != "\n":
```

Comment: I checked before this and for the "rsite = desc_values[1].lstrip('RBS0')
  IndexError: list index out of range" and checked if length is > 2 "len(desc_values) > 2" and the error disappeared i read it somewhere but for the lines[x] still working on it .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it although i don't know if it is correct way but it works.
I think the problem was that the x was exceeding the length of the list lines containing the file and there had to be a check after the split that the list had length larger or equal to number of elements so :

```
           if len(desc_values) > 2 and len(desc) > 2:
                    rsite = desc_values[1].lstrip('RBS0')
                    print "\t"*2 + "rsite:" + rsite 

                    if desc[-1] == "ALARM SLOGAN\n":
                        alarm_slogan = desc_values[-1]
                        print alarm_slogan



                x = i
                print x #to check the line
                print len(lines) # check length of lines
                while [x] < len(lines): #check so that x doesnt exceed the length of file list "line"

                    while not lines[x].startswith("EXTERNAL"):
                        x+=1
                    if lines[x].startswith("EXTERNAL"):
                        while lines[x] != "\n":
                            print lines[x]
                            x+=1
```

Thank you man you really helped me although i am trying to find a way to stop the iteration of x to gain some computation time i tried break but it throws you completely of the loop.
Thanks anyway

Comment: but you know i think the concept is correct  i thought that after while becomes false it terminates (exits) so the increment of x should have stopped and the program flow continues